# Advise on visual appearance of equation: use \text{} or not?

Tags: equations

Would you advise to use "\text{}" for variable names in an equation or not (in a paper on econometrics)?
Equation 2.1 is *with* the use of "\text{}" and equation 2.2 *without*. [image]

Comment: You shouldn't use \text but `\mathit` or `\mathsf`. `\text` is for text like `and follows`, not for math variables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! No, correct is `mathrm{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

No never use `\text` for variable names  but never use the default math italic either.

`\text` selects the text font current ouside the math, so for example will be italic in a theorem. It is useful if you want to get a phrase of non-mathematical text inside the display.

The default math italic font uses wide sidebearings so adjacent letters do not look like a word, but look like a product of one-letter variables.

Use `\mathrm{Gini}` to get a roman upright identifier.